# excel letter with vector symbol above it in text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to use the symbol for accelaration (a with an arrow above) in text in excel. I tried searching in symbols and using shapecatcher, but I couldn't find that possibility. I don't want to use insert equation, because this inserts a extra textbox.

For clarity this is what I want:
[image]